# Groovy tests on Java class

Tags: groovy, spock

I am using Spock to test a Java class.

When both were in "default" packages I got "No such property" error in IntelliJ IDEA, if I recall correctly it worked fine in Eclipse.
Importing Java class solves the problem.

This works:

```
def var = new MyClass()
def result = var.doStuff()
```

While this does not, without a static import:

```
def result = MyClass.doStuff()
```

Is there a way to fix this without an implicit import?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean - maybe you can provide more details.  I created the following sample java class and a very short spock test and had no problems.

```
/**
 * Created by mike on 1/29/14.
 */
public class SampleJava {

private int count;
private String text;

public SampleJava(int cnt, String input) {
    count = cnt;
    text = input;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SampleJava{" +
            "count=" + count +
            ", text='" + text + '\'' +
            '}';
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

    public static void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("doStuff...");
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SampleJava sj = new SampleJava(5, "Hello");
    System.out.println(sj);
}
}
```

Here's the spock test

```
/**
 * Created by mike on 1/29/14.
 */
import  spock.lang.Specification

class TestSampleJava extends Specification {

SampleJava sampleJava

def "test constructor"() {
    sampleJava = new SampleJava(5, "Hello")

    expect:
    sampleJava.count == 5
    sampleJava.text == 'Hello'
    SampleJava.doStuff()
   }

}
```

Comment: Check out my updated question. The issue is with calls to static methods. Also, I think it worked fine in Eclipse, but now I am in IntelliJ and it gives me "No such property" error.